# Avoiding increases in 404 errors after massive URL deletion

Tags: 404

We have a relatively new website (no external links, PR0, DA17) and we are making a major change in content. On the one hand we have to incorporate new content and otherwise eliminate much old content.

When we finally make this change, for several reasons, more than 100,000 URLs will give a `404` error. The main reason is that the URL pattern of products will change from something like `example.com/1871-producto1/` to `example.com/producto1/`

**How would you recommend to proceed in order to minimize page not found errors?**

In most cases, we will do a `301` redirect. But we do not want to abuse these redirects.

So far we are blocking `404` pages using `robots.txt` and manually de-indexing many from Webmaster tools, [as explained by Google here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/easier-url-removals-for-site-owners.html).

**Would you launch the site with this big amount of 404 errors, hoping that they will gradually disappear, or would you clean them in any other way?**

Answer (score 3):

They will disappear and it will only affect your rank for a short amount of time. Return a `301` Response **AS MUCH AS YOU CAN**, every page you can save, is some PR you've saved.

All the pages which give `404`, give them a custom page. It will help a tiny bit to create a custom `404` page (because you understand UX, according to Google). `404` pages will get removed from the index faster than blocked pages, for a simple reason:
`-> 404 header -> page does not exist, remove from index`
`-> no crawler access. Might still be there for user, so no remove from index`

BTW: You're not abusing the `301` if you use it what it's for: Indication that the content has been permanently relocated ;)

Comment: Hi, So does this mean, that every single page that has 404, should be redirected to say our homepage?

And by this logic, any random links like `example.com/$$##@` that don't actually exist should also be redirected, or this last bit wrong?

Comment: Both are wrong :) Redirect to a similar page. Think as a user: If you're looking for purple circled puppies, do you want to end up on a generic homepage? (No, no you don't ;) ). Instead, make a soft/custom 404 page. There is plenty on the internet about this.

Answer (score 3):

The Google Webmaster blog page you linked to was explaining how to deal with URL removals via the removal tool. You should not need to use the removal tool for normal site maintenance. And you should not block `404` pages with `robots.txt` as Google will not be able to crawl the pages to see the `404` response.

See here :

> Don’t use the URL tool to get rid of pages in these circumstances:
>
> To clean up cruft, like old pages that `404`. If you recently changed
>   your site and now have some outdated URLs in the index, Google's
>   crawlers will see this as we recrawl your URLs, and those pages will
>   naturally drop out of our search results. There's no need to request
>   an urgent removal.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1269119?hl=en

As indicated by Martijn, `301` redirect as many URLs as you can (and those you cant, return a `404` response)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, use `301` links. However, in this case instead of bulk `301` redirects manually, and I'm sure you already know this. But you could always use a regex to match the pattern and redirect traffic to the correct page. For example, redirecting `example.com/product/abc` to `example.com` will give you no benefit at all where as matching `example.com/product/abc` and matching the `/product/` and redirecting to `/product-abc/` would obviously be much better. This way, in between time Google will firstly know which is the new URL, all current traffic going to the `404` would now be redirected to the correct page hence no major loss in traffic.

Personally, with regards to massive amounts of `404`'s on the website and then letting them fade out. If I see a big website and get presented with a `404` error I sort of think if there not going to redirect me to a relevant page, then why should I bother. It's much more professional to redirect the user to an appropriate page that is related than just to leave the user sitting and wondering why your "website isn't working".